# Accumulating supposedly deleted files - Mint

Tags: linux-mint

- Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit 2.6.13
- Linux Kernel 3.13.0-37 generic
- Processor AMD A8-5500 APU with Radeon HD Graphcs x 2
- Memory 7.7 GiB
- Hard Drives 450.2 GB
- Graphicx Card AMD Seymour (Radeon HD 6400M/7400 M series VGA cntroller

**Problem:** Masses of former (now deleted) files, applets, programs, etc. apparently from when I first installed Mint to the present time. If given the option by the popup, Delete is usually chosen not just sending to Trash. With the Trash option, Trash along with Recent Files (Mint Menu) are cleared periodically and at the end of day. Nothing, I think, should remain.

**How Did I Find This?** By accident for the most part. I called up a directory for a file using Scribus. Not only was the desired file present but masses of others that should have been deleted and gone. Not just in Scribus but elsewhere. Apologies but I didn't keep a list.

**Question:** Aside from being irritating is this a problem? If so, how do I truly delete and prevent a repeat?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is not really clear. Can you describe *what you do* and *where these files accumulate*? The way you describe it, it reads like "somehow" files that *somebody unbeknownst* has deleted, accumulate "somewhere" on your computer. And you ask "Is this a problem". I am very inclined to answer: "No, this is not a problem if you have a harddrive big enough"